# Area chart google charts mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, json, charts, google-visualization

I have this query to select the data from my database.

```
SELECT monthname(DATA), sum(val1) DESPESAS, sum(val2) RECEITAS 
   from (
     SELECT DATA, val1, val2 
        from (SELECT DATA, loja_id, valor val1, 0 val2 
             from despesas WHERE YEAR(DATA) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND loja_id = '1') s1  
          union 
          (SELECT DATA loja_id, 0 val1, valor val2
             from receitas WHERE YEAR(DATA) = YEAR(CURDATE()) and loja_id = '1') ) t 
   group by month(DATA) 
   order by DATA
```

And it return the total sum of months in a table like this:

```
MES         -       DESPESAS         -      RECEITAS
January     -       R$16,29          -     R$355,00
February    -       R$120,00         -     R$107,29
March       -       R$124,06         -     R$0,00
April       -       R$0,00           -     R$38,00
May         -       R$130,91         -     R$37,00
July         -      R$0,00           -     R$10,00
```

How can I generate a chart with google chart with this values:

```
cols = months and line 1 = despesas line 2 - receitas
```

i'm generating manually like this

```
 google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Mes', 'Receitas', 'Despesas'],
    ['Janeiro',  0,      0],
    ['Fevereiro',  0,      0],
    ['Março',  1315.98,       0],
    ['Abril',  1066.08,      0],
    ['Maio',  1764.04,      0],
    ['Junho',  1875.59,      181.46],
    ['Julho',  1850.54,      2102.84],
    ['Agosto',  2980,      2527.6],
    ['Setembro',  0,      0],
    ['Outubro',  0,      0],
    ['Novembro',  0,      0],
    ['Dezembro',  0,      0]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Despesas e Receitas Almirante',
      hAxis: {title: 'Mes',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
      vAxis: {minValue: 0},
      series: {
        0: { color: '#0000FF' },
        1: { color: '#FF0000' },
      }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_Almirante'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

Comment: Have you ever tried something?